# connect 2 audio inputs to 1 output using an audiosplitter

Tags: audio

Alright guys, gals and overall people who are smarter than me,

I recently wanted to play some games on my laptop while also watching a youtube video on my phone at 3 A.M., so to not disturb my family I would need to use a pair of earbuds, but then I only had the option to get the gamesounds or the youtube sounds, so I went online to see if there was an easy software solution for this, which there was not (multi device wireless audio mixing is apparently quite a niche market). After about an hour of googling, I noticed an audio splitter lying next to me with a couple of 3mm male to male cables when I got an idea;

Would it be possible to put the two 3mm male to male cables in audio splitter, one to my phone and one to my laptop and then connect my earbuds to the third input of the splitter(see the schematic if i can't explain it very well), or will that just blow up my equipment? If it's save, would the audio even sound right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fekfnk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this answers my question perfectly, please make it an answer so you get rewarded accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't connect the outputs directly together, as that might blow something.

Google `DIY passive mixer` and/or click [this link](http://epanorama.net/circuits/linesum.html).

Since you want to drive headphone speakers, you may even want an active mixer, but then it gets slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

directly connecting the outputs together isn't safe, to the extent that those two outputs are meant to drive a low-impedance load.

you can, however, connect them together through small resistors. the volume for each source / output will be lower but you do get to hear them all.